# Docker with Redis via Procfile.dev in iTerm2 output is unreadable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, redis, procfile

This is a bit of a strange one and I can't find answers anywhere else... if I have a `Procfile.dev` file with a basic Redis command in it such as `redis: docker run --rm -it -p 6379:6379 redis:latest` and run it via `bin/dev` the output from the Redis ascii art makes the logs unreable. If I remove the Redis command from the `Procfile.dev` it goes back to being neat and readable, below is an example of the messed up output:

[image: Docker running via bin/dev via a Procfile.dev]

Does anyone know how to make this look nice? I'm having to run docker outside the procfile atm because of this.

This is a Ruby on Rails 7 app running via `bin/dev`, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible try running the docker container in non interactive mode:

```
redis: docker run --rm -p 6379:6379 redis:latest
```

Note the removal of the `-it` flag.

It will cause redis to not output the logo ascii art.

The reasoning behind the solution are the [comments](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/cc97f4cf354a38340ac6c2894ab2638de9cb44bc/redis.conf#L381-L388) defined for the configuration property `always-show-logo` that you can see in `redis.conf`:

```
# By default Redis shows an ASCII art logo only when started to log to the
# standard output and if the standard output is a TTY and syslog logging is
# disabled. Basically this means that normally a logo is displayed only in
# interactive sessions.
```

Similar issues has been reported for the service, like [this one](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/1935) related to `syslog`.